# keras plotting loss and MSE

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras, regression, matplotlib

Can someone give me a tip on how I could incorporate MSE & loss plots? I have been following some [machinelearningmastery](https://machinelearningmastery.com/display-deep-learning-model-training-history-in-keras/) posts to plot this but the application is classification and I am attempting regression. Also what is different in my script is I am defining the model thru calling a function, so I am curious if my script could be re-written without the function `def wider_model()` that defines the model.

This script below works except what is commented out on the bottom for the `plt` plots. In the machinelearningmastery post, someone does ask this question how to do for regression, and supposedly if you print `print(history.history.keys())` two values are returned for `dict_keys([‘mean_absolute_error’, ‘loss’])`...

Any tips help, there isn't a lot of wisdom here... Thank you

```
import numpy
import pandas
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math



# load dataset
dataset = pandas.read_csv("prepdSPdata.csv", index_col='Date', parse_dates=True)

# shuffle dataset
dataset = dataset.sample(frac=1.0)


# split into input (X) and output (Y) variables
X = numpy.array(dataset.drop(['Demand'],1))
Y = numpy.array(dataset['Demand'])

print(dataset.shape)
print(dataset.dtypes)
print(dataset.columns)


def wider_model():
    # create model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(20, input_dim=11, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(10, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1, kernel_initializer='normal'))
    # Compile model
    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
    return model


# fix random seed for reproducibility
seed = 7
numpy.random.seed(seed)
estimators = []
estimators.append(('standardize', StandardScaler()))
estimators.append(('mlp', KerasRegressor(build_fn=wider_model, epochs=1, batch_size=5, verbose=0)))
pipeline = Pipeline(estimators)
kfold = KFold(n_splits=10, random_state=seed)
results = cross_val_score(pipeline, X, Y, cv=kfold)
print("Wider: %.2f (%.2f) MSE" % (results.mean(), results.std()))
print("RMSE", math.sqrt(results.std()))



# list all data in history
#print(wider_model.wider_model.keys())

# summarize history for MSE
#plt.plot(history.history['acc'])
#plt.plot(history.history['val_acc'])
#plt.title('model MSE')
#plt.ylabel('MSE')
#plt.xlabel('epoch')
#plt.legend(['train', 'test'], loc='upper left')
#plt.show()

# summarize history for loss
#plt.plot(history.history['loss'])
#plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'])
#plt.title('model loss')
#plt.ylabel('loss')
#plt.xlabel('epoch')
#plt.legend(['train', 'test'], loc='upper left')
#plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cross_val_score` does not return the history of the training. You can use `fit` instead:

```
history = model.fit( ...
```

See this [example](https://machinelearningmastery.com/custom-metrics-deep-learning-keras-python/).

As you mentioned, the `history` object holds the results of the training for each epoch.

Here is the relevant bit:

```
history = model.fit(X, X, epochs=500, batch_size=len(X), verbose=2)
pyplot.plot(history.history['mean_squared_error'])
pyplot.plot(history.history['mean_absolute_error'])
pyplot.plot(history.history['mean_absolute_percentage_error'])
pyplot.plot(history.history['cosine_proximity'])
pyplot.show()
```

I was actually working on the same example that you referenced yesterday. I think it is hard to understand because it introduces many functions and concepts: estimators, `StandardScaler`, `KerasRegressor`, `Pipeline`, `KFold` and `cross_val_score`.

However, I did like the approach to creating and testing models, and Cross Validation would produce more robust models.

Answer (score 1):

You're only training your model for 1 epoch so you're only giving it one data point to work from. If you want to plot a line of loss or accuracy you need to train for more epochs.

Comment: Sorry that was jus testing my code I am training for about 100 epochs

Comment: Ah okay, could you give more explanation as to why the commented code doesn’t work?

Comment: `cross_val_score` does not return the `history` of the training. You can use `fit` instad: `history = model.fit( ...`

Comment: Here is an example: https://machinelearningmastery.com/custom-metrics-deep-learning-keras-python/

Comment: @BSeven submit this as an answer! 